# Estimating correct coefficient when error term correlated with regressor?

Tags: regression, simulation, endogeneity, consistency

Suppose we have the following **causal** relationships (I put $=$ but they can be $\leftarrow$ for causality).
$$\tag{1}
Z=\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 c + \epsilon_z
$$
$$\tag{2}X = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \sqrt[3]{Z} + \epsilon_x$$
$$\tag{3}
Y = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 X + c
$$
with $\epsilon_z,\epsilon_x,c$ all independent of eachother and identically distributed (assume standard normal distribution for simplicity).

**Suppose** you have data of $n$ observations on $(Z_i, X_i,Y_i)$.

Here are my questions:

1. Is there a way to consistently estimate $\gamma_1$ with the data (supposed that) we have?
2. If I regress $X_i$ on $\sqrt[3]{Z_i}$ and then regress $Y_i$ on the residuals from this first stage, does that give me a consistent estimate? **Why or why not**?

---

### My thoughts:

If we regress $Y$ on $X$ we have an endogeneity issue. Okay, I understand this.

Where I am confused is whether I lose something by regressing $X_i$ on $\sqrt[3]{Z_i}$ and then regress $Y_i$ on the residuals from this first stage?

Specifically, doing the above two stages gets rid of the endogeneity problem. However, now the regressor I am using does not include the impact that $Z$ would have on $Y$ (this gets taken into the error term). I am not sure whether this matters?

The reason I am not sure whether this matters is because

1. If we just think about the $\frac{cov(Y,X)}{var(X)}$ formula, in this two stage formulation, I believe this fraction becomes $\gamma_1$. (Because no endoneity issue).
2. Just thinking about the data, there should now be a direct relationship between the regressor in the second stage (i.e. the residuals from the first stage) and $Y$. That is, if these residuals increase by $1$, then $y$ should also increase by $\gamma_1$. Thus, I imagine OLS should pick up this relationship.

---

### I tried doing simulations

And,while for many of the parameter values I tried I get pretty close to the true values (that I set). For others though I think I'm pretty far off (for example, there was a time when I was getting an estimate of ~2.5 when $\gamma_1$ was set to 3)

Additionally, I tried the simulation with as many observations as I could muster (For example, I tried 50 millions observations and estimation $~2.5$ when the true value was $3$).

Maybe I just found parameter values that converge extremely slowly -- I don't know.

Comment: Given you already did some simulation, why do not try fit the model (3) only to see if you can get the unbiased estimate of that parameter? What do you mean by "consistency"?

Comment: @J.Wang I did not check for unbiasedness. Good point. By consistency I mean that the probability limit of the estimate is the true parameters. That is, that $\forall \epsilon >0$, $$P(\vert \hat{\beta}-\beta\vert>\epsilon)\to 0\quad \text{as } N\to \infty$$, where $N$ is the number of observations.

Comment: In fact, if you check your model (3) against the assumptions of linear model, you will find all of the assumptions are met. And also the error terms following the normal distribution. Then least square estimate of the slope in model (3), which is what you want, is the best as proved mathematically long ago. How to judge the consistency in simulation?

Comment: @J.Wang The assumptions are not met in model (3). The question states that we have data on $X,Y,Z$, not on $c$. Hence a regression of $Y$ on $X$ omitting $c$ will have correlation between the error term and $X$: An omitted variables problem.

Comment: Yes, c is not in the data in the real application. But in your simulation dataset, you should have c and X. Why do not try to calculate the Pearson correlation coefficient to see if c and  X are correlated. From your equations (1) - (3), c and X are independent.